# C++ delete storage space in a different function from where it was allocated

Tags: c++

Will I get undefined behavior if I delete a storage space in a different function from where the space was originally allocated?

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int Data1;
    unsigned int Data2;
    unsigned int Data3;
}TData;

void CreateStorage(void)
{
    TData *TempData = new TData;

    DeleteStorage((unsigned char*)TempData); 
}

void DeleteStorage(unsigned char *StorageToDelete)
{
    delete (TData*)StorageToDelete;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allocating and deleting memory from different functions is completely valid.

Answer (score 1):

No.

[*Note: you don't need that cast.*]

Comment: What you mean "you don't need that cast"? He allocated a TData and without the cast he would delete a unsigned char. If the static type doesn't match the dynamic type you get undefined behavior when deleting.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: The question has been edited.  Originally, there were no `unsigned char *` anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're allocating and deallocating within the same library, it will be deleted safely.

However, there are things to note if you are allocating and deallocating in different libraries. Since the underlying class definition may be different amongst different libraries, you need to make sure that you're using the same definition.

One very common problem that arises is when you're using a precompiled open source C++ library and your program and the library use different C++ runtime library, it will sometimes crash while the open source library deallocates a STL container instance that has been allocated by your program because the definition of that class in the open source library is different from yours. The common workaround in solving this problem is to recompile the open source library using the compiler that you use.

Comment: I'm using QT. The storage pointer is actually passed as an event to the other function:

Comment: @user668773 It's going to be fine if the destructor of that storage is defined in  the library **only**

Answer (score -1):

No, it's ok. 
Why do you cast StorageToDelete to (TData*) in DeleteStorage()?

Answer (score -1):

No, that's fine, and also don't typedef your structs. Just say `struct TData { /*...*/ };`.

Comment: I'm using QT. The storage pointer is actually passed as an event to the other function (emit signalDeleteStorage). I'm not allowed to pass an undefined type in a signal event. I therefore pass the pointer as known type, unsigned char. TData is unknown and I therefore cast it to unsigned char when I pass it. Just to make sure the compiler knows what size memory to de-allocate, I cast it back to its original type. Is this unnecessary?

Comment: Sorry, I misread that; I'll remove the second point. Indeed, `delete` will invoke the destructor, so you should give it the correct type. Not because of memory freeing (which should be fine), but because of object destruction. You should pass such an "typeless" pointer as a `void *`, though, and just to be tidy, say `delete static_cast<TData*>(StorageToDelete)`.

Comment: The reason for using type defined structures could be due to bad habits but may also be due to my programming style. I often pass structures as pointers to other functions. Without much hassle I can now use the type defined structure in the function argument list when passing the pointer. This way no casting is required when operating on the structure pointer. Off course the example given does not apply since it is passed as an unsigned char but in all other cases I will pass it by the structure type.